# Firestore + Swift Query - Check for value within an array in specified document

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to check for value within an array if you're querying for a specific document ID?

This doesn't work:

```
let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "nil"
let db = Firestore.firestore()
db.collection("users").document(userID).whereField("favorites", arrayContains: productID)
```

Seems like you can only use .whereField directly after declaring the collection, but not on the document.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of the `where` methods is to find docs in a collection satisfying some criterion.

If you've already got a doc ref, just `get()` it and check the array in the client.

Alternatively, query the collection with where, and see if your user id is one of the ids in the resulting snapshot.